# Display html for selected products or products categories

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Hello I am using advanced custom field plugin for displaying some html only for selected products or only for products for selected categories in option page with relationship picker. My result instead is displaying for all products. This is what I have:

```html
$products = get_field('products_picker', 'option');
$categories =  get_field('categories_picker', 'option');
$prom_img = get_field('prom_img', 'option');


if ( $products ) {

 foreach( $products as $p ):
 
       if( $post->ID == $p->ID ):

  <img src="<?php echo  $prom_img['url']; ?>">


    endif;
 endforeach;
  }

 if ( $categories ) {

 foreach( $categories as $term ):
 
       $category = get_term( $term );
    
   if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $post )) {
      ?>

 <img src="<?php echo  $prom_img['url']; ?>">

    endif;
 endforeach;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In similar cases I create a new wp_query passing the array with the post IDs like below:

```
 $posts = get_field('products_picker', 'option');
 $new_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'     => array('post'),
  'post__in'      => $posts,
  'orderby'       => 'post__in',
 ));

if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();

//your code here

endwhile;
endif;
```

For the categories part you can use a query like this:

```
  $categories =  get_field('categories_picker', 'option');
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'category',
              'field' => 'term_id',
              'terms' => $categories[0]
          )
       )
  );
  $cat_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with this code on product category page all products are replaced with the first product selected in relationship picker and is adding the html/ image ( $prom_img in my example )  multiple times equal with the number of products in that category

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question right. You don't want to filter those posts in a result page, but you want to display something to their current "single product page" or the "archive page", is that correct?

Comment: NO, I don't want to filter them, I only want to display that html only for the selected products in the picker. Actually that html is an image badge which will be displayed on top of products image. So it will show on products category page and also on single product page. And I have another picker where I can select products categories instead. So if this one is selected the html is displayed on all products from the selected categories.

Comment: If that so, I think you can achieve your goal by searching for the `current ID` in the table `$posts = get_field('products_picker', 'option');` and if exists display the `img`

Comment: Hey I fixed for products picker, I edited my code, but I can't get it to work for categories picker

Comment: That's because you are not listing the posts in the categories. You have to list the posts and then search in the loop if a post has any of the custom field terms. You can use `if has_terms` check here for help -> [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/). Another option is to list the post included in your custom field selection (I updated my answer with a $categories example)

Comment: Thanks but I found  a simpler solution, I reedited my code, for both products and categories is working

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this in Wordpress, but the first thing I would try is to rename the $post variable that pulls the ACF field to '$posts' (plural).

Then change the foreach loop as follows.

```html
$posts = get_field('products_picker', 'option');
$prom_img = get_field('prom_img', 'option');


if ( $posts ) {

 foreach( $posts as $post ):

  setup_postdata($post);
   
$sales_html = '<div class="promo-badge test"><img src=' . $prom_img['url'] . '></div>';

  wp_reset_postdata();
 endforeach;
  }
```

That might fix it... I'm not sure you won't need to turn the foreach loop into an actual Wordpress style loop (the type with `while(have_posts()): the_post();` etc. like in @kaize answer below)

See here if my solution didn't help: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/